# Is there a way to apply different CSS properties for different browsers?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am making a website. I want to hide a element when I open Chrome browser, but that element won't hide when it is opened in Firefox. In short, I just have to change the `display` property in CSS to hide or un-hide the element in different browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

1. One way is to use media queries that target a specific browser. This is awkward to work with and i'm not sure there are media queries for all browsers, [here you can read more about it](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/create-browser-specific-css)

   Example:

   ```
   /* on Chrome version 29 and above */
   @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0 and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
       .my-class {
           background-color: red;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Another possibility is for you to find what the used browser with JS ([can read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browsers)) and then add some kind of class or attribute to your element or to the body itself. You can then use this to style the element as you need

   Example:

   ```
   const isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
   if (isChrome) {
       document.body.setAttribute('os', 'chrome');
   }
   ```

   and then on your css

   ```
   body[os="chrome"] .your-class {
       background-color: blue;
   }
   ```